# VB.Net Search a string

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am searching a string of DNA chars, ATCG. I may wish to look for AT for example and the search must ignore ATAT not find two AT's. I need to know how many AT,s there are in the string and their position in there position.
I tried various ideas but so far have failed. I used Mid, Contains. If someone can give me a hint I would be grateful.
Regards

Comment: Add the code and example data you're currently trying. Add your error message or incorrect results - does your code compile?

Answer (score 0):

Not a VB.NET dude (C# is my current dope), but luckily they're similar. If you don't care about execution time, you can just brute force it. First, see if your pattern occurs in the string at all:

```
bool containsAT myDNAChars.Contains( "AT" );
```

Then you can go about finding their positions:

```
var myListOfMatches = new List<int>();
int searchIndex = 0;
string pattern = "AT";
bool done = false;
while( !done )
{
    int atIndex = myDNAChars.IndexOf( pattern, searchIndex );
    myListOfMatches.Add( atIndex );
    searchIndex += pattern.Length;
    if( searchIndex > myDNAChars.Length )
    {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Once you have a list of matches, you can iterate over it and discard any occurrences of "ATAT" or any other patterns you don't want.

It's not elegant--it's brute force--but it should work.

Sorry about the C#, but it should be easy to convert to VB.NET.